# Find best route in route table using sorting

Tags: router, ip-forwarding-table, prefix, route, route-table

I am trying to implement a forwarding algorithm by myself with ARP, ICMP and the forwarding algorithms. Given the routing table:

```
typedef struct route_table_entry {
    uint32_t prefix;
    uint32_t next_hop;
    uint32_t mask;
    int interface;
} route_table;
```

Is it enough to sort this table by the mask in an descending order to reduce the time spent finding next_hop to `O(log n)` from `O(n)`? Because in my mind this doesn't really make sense, what if it doesn't find any match? then the algorithm is still `O(n)`. If someone could explain this to me it would be appreciated.

Comment: While your programming question is off-topic here, the general algorithm is to sort by prefix length and same-length prefixes by metric. Then, the first hit (searching from longest to shortest prefix) is your route. If no match is found, there's no route, the packet is dropped, and an ICMP message is returned.

Comment: Sadly homework questions are off topic here.

Comment: You could implement a trie. That is how Cisco does CEF. You look up the address in the trie to find the location of the route elsewhere. Also, routers can use TCAM, and you could try to implement that algorithm in software.

Comment: By the way, routers drop packets for which they have no route. If you add the `0.0.0.0/0` route, that will match every address, and it has the shortest possible prefix, so it will be a default route (route of last resort), and that is used for routers that route to the Internet but do not want the full Internet routing table (approaching a million routes).

Answer (score 1):

This is a really detailed, illustrated [blog post](https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2017-ipv4-route-lookup-linux) explaining several popular IPv4 lookup algorithms which are used by modern routers and operating systems.

In your initial post, you mention sorting; and I believe the method you are considering implies you'd then need to scan the results.  You could compare that to scanning a database table to find a string.  Modern databases have indexes which make searching for a string more efficient.  The tree-like data structures illustrated in the blog post I mention are used similarly to databases which index text for faster searching.

I hope this database/text analogy might help you re-frame your question into terms you are already familiar with.